# Splitting up electrical lines to kitchen

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, kitchens, subpanel, rewire

I am beginning to renovate my kitchen and have a pair of 30 A breakers for the electric oven, and a pair for the electric stove. I am going to install gas stove and gas oven. I wanted to use one pair or both  as the dedicated kitchen/small appliance Circuit. And switch out the breakers for GFCI/AFCI Breakers?

Comment: Can I ask why you're going gas?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel  This is just a comment/opinion, but I've cooked on both electric and gas and much prefer gas.  Why?  1) you have instantaneous control of the burner setting, 2) I find it to be much more robust than electric, I do a lot of stir fry and it requires high heat, there's a reason most restaurants use gas. 3)  I can still cook if the power goes out. But and here's the big BUT...if were to revert to electric, I'd go induction. I help cook at my church for large groups and we have 4 3,500 watt (240v) induction burners and they are awesome.

Comment: @GeorgeAnderson -- yeah, induction is the way to go for cooking these days, I wouldn't recommend a conventional electric range to anyone

Answer (score 1):

I think gas is great for a cooktop but not for an oven. You may want to consider sticking with an electric oven as gas has no real advantages over electric for an oven.

You can replace a 30A double breaker with a 20A double breaker and use that for two kitchen receptacle circuits. Depending on the wiring, GFCI may be easier, but less convenient, at the breaker than at the receptacles. AFCI is likely not required for those circuits.

Keep in mind that a gas cooktop and oven will require electricity. I believe the cooktop ignition is one of the few exceptions that can be on the required kitchen receptacle circuits. I also recommend getting a cooktop that can be started with a match if the electricity is out - most can be, but not all.

Comment: I'm not going to flag this, but your answer is opinion based. I have a gas oven and it's great. Moisture is a byproduct of gas combustion and tends to be gentler on foods in the oven than pure electric.

Comment: First paragraph is opinion. But the rest is a real answer.